# Cannot connect to home VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I've got a HP Microserver at home running Windows 7 and it sits behind a BT Infinity HomeHub Router.

Basically I followed the instructions [here](http://www.howtonetworking.com/VPN/win7vpn1.htm).

And then on my router I allowed the following to my server:

```
TCP 1723-1723 1723-1723
UDP 500-500 500-500
TCP 170-1701 1701-1701
```

However I can't get my phone (Galaxy Nexus) nor my iPad to connect to the VPN. I've done a ping test and I can resolve the IP.
I'm using dyndns if that makes any difference, however I direct IP to my home network doesnt work either

Any ideas?

I get these messages on my servers event logs

> The following error occurred in the Point to Point Protocol module on
>   port: VPN3-1, UserName: MediaServer\vpn. The remote computer does not
>   support the required data encryption type.
>
> CoId={NA}: The user MediaServer\vpn connected to port VPN3-1 has been
>   disconnected because no network protocols were successfully
>   negotiated.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the following event log system error:

```
CoId={NA}: The user *** connected to port VPN3-1 has been disconnected because no network protocols were successfully negotiated.
```

I was able to get rid of the error thanks to [K20GH's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/471044/cannot-connect-to-home-vpn/529609#comment555164_471045). Here are the steps I followed:

1. Right-click the network icon in the notification area and select "Open Network and Sharing Center"
2. Click "Change adapter settings"
3. Right-click "Incoming connections" and select Properties
4. On the Networking tab, select IPv4 and click Properties
5. Select "Specify IP addresses" and enter a range of IP addresses

Android VPN client is able to connect successfully now to my Windows 7 laptop after doing the above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to permit the [GRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation) protocol many low-end routers don't support this, or only support this when you set the VPN server as the 'DMZ' device.

Comment: I've added the server as the DMZ device, however the connection gets rejected immediately now

Comment: That is good, now check the event logs on your 'server'.

Comment: I appear to have these messages - see updated question

Comment: Done it

From Network Connections
Right Click "Server Name"(local)
Select Properties
Select IP Tab
Under IP address assignment select "Static Address Pool" and assign a pool
of ip addresses from within the range of the IP addresses available from the
DHCP server.

After doing this I am able to connect.

Comment: @K20GH Can you add your solution here as an "answer" so that it can be accepted?